# I cant install updates or Python

Tags: updates, python, repository

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/eoan/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu eoan InRelease' is not signed.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:armagetronad-dev/ppa
sudo apt update -q
```

It did no work. Im so lost. New to Linux. Main purpose is to install python. Thats When I discovered the issue.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Starting from 18.04, Ubuntu ships with Python3. You don't have to install anything on top or it.

Comment: The [jonathan ppa](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf) is no longer available to the public (but you don't need it because python3.6 is available on eoan without it) and if you go to the [deadsnakes ppa page](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index#sources-list-entries) and select the dropdown menu for "published in" on the left, you will see that "eoan" is not listed as an option so no packages are available for 19.10.

Comment: The same goes for the [tista/adapta ppa](https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/adapta/+index#sources-list-entries), the drop-down menu only shows "cosmic" and "bionic" so no packages are available for 19.10.

Answer (score 1):

You have added the PPAs which are not supported for your Ubuntu release.
So you need to remove this PPAs first:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:tista/adapta
```

then update package lists and install updates with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and you are done.

Please note that your system already have Python2 and Python3 installed. They are available as `python2` and `python3`.

---

Documentation (man-pages) for commands used:

- [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)
- [`ppa-purge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html)
- [`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you visited Jonathon's Overview page on Launchpad?
https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf

He clearly states that the PPD you are attempting to access is not public.  Have you made a donation toward his efforts?

That is probably not your main issue.  I believe you already have Python3 installed.

---

Let's get to the real issues here.

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Python 3.6 installed.  Which version have you installed on your system?

Try this in a Terminal window:

---

$ which python3

---

$ python3 --version

---

Those two commands will tell you if you have python3 installed or not, where it is located, and which version you have installed.

If you have the full updated Ubuntu 18.04 installed you should have Python3, version 3.6.9.

WARNING:  I suggest that as a beginner to python you do not use PPAs.

Hope this helps!

--Dave